# Unable to start main activity which has build by maven

Tags: android, maven, classnotfoundexception

I had three proejct: parent, source and a library project.
My problem is the following: after successful mvn install android:deploy android:run the application get`s crash with the following message:

```
05-04 17:22:10.564: E/AndroidRuntime(6574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 17:22:10.564: E/AndroidRuntime(6574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate  
activity ComponentInfo{com.fruit.apple/com.fruit.apple.SplashScreenActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fruit.apple.SplashScreenActivity in loader 

dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/mnt/asec/com.fruit.apple-1/pkg.apk]
```

Actually I don`t know what should be there problem, I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Karoly

PS
part of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <sign>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </sign>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${android.sdk.path}</path>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related to maven. If you are using Maps v1, make sure you have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` under the `<application>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Hi rciovati ! The splashScreenActivity is not GoogleAcitivty,just a simple activity. And there is <uses-library> in the application tag.

Comment: okay ! I had used dex2jar and JD GUI and as I see now, somehow my own classes are missing from the final apk. All of the library are represented in the dex, except my classes.

Comment: I see. From the portion of the pom.xml file I can't see whats wrong. BTW, have you tried with the newer version of the plugin? You have 3.2.0, the current version is 3.5.3.

Comment: As I see now my target/classes are empty after "Successful" build.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had Solved the problem:
I have a parent project with two modules and maven compiler 2.3.2, with configuration tags where I set only the source and target to 1.6.
Modile 1: library for module 2 , apklib packaging
Modile 2: Source code of app with apk packaging.

-in module 1 and mobule 2 I use src/main/java as src folder and src/test/java for test.
-no eclipse dependeny in classpath between projects, only maven one.

Thx Rciovati for your note about version.